# How do I isolate random strings in a list with a specific pattern inside?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this list:

```py
sample_list = ['apple juice', 'summer, winter, spring, fall', 'mango', 'dirt']
```

I want to find the string inside this list that has a comma and separate the words inside them, but in order for that to happen, it needs to know to only separate everything BETWEEN the commas because the string might change (so you can't do something like  `remove.suffix('summer')` or `remove.suffix('winter')` etc. Next time it might be `['apple juice', 'ok, yes, no', 'mango', 'dirt']`.

How would I approach this? Keep in mind strings will not always be English words, I want it to work on any string.

Here's as far as I got:

```py
sample_list = ['apple juice', 'summer, winter, spring, fall', 'mango', 'dirt']

for var in sample_list:
    if ',' in var:
        if 
        print(var)
```

Current output: `summer, winter, spring, fall`
Desired output: `['summer', 'winter', 'spring', 'fall']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you just want to split your string when the string contains a comma. To do so, you can use the `str.split()` method.

```py
sample_list = [...]

for var in sample_list:
    if "," in var:
        print(var.split(", "))
```